# Getting an error for $_server['SCRIPT_NAME']

Tags: php

I am trying to get path of page via

```
<?php

/**
* @author 
* @copyright 2013
*/

$current_file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
echo $current_file;


?>
```

It gives an error Notice: Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME

Also I included it in my login page code

```
<form action="<?php echo $current_file;?>" method="POST">
Username : <input type="text" name="username"/> Password : <input type="password" name="password" />
<input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
</form>
```

It also gives an error regarding $current_file

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @YadavChetan **It gives an error Notice: Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME**

Comment: @YadavChetan- "Undefined Index"

Answer (score 7):

from [`php Manual`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

> Under Windows 2000, running IIS and PHP 4.3.10,
>   $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is not available, however
>   $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] is present and seems to contain the same
>   information

also one more theory

> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] may not
>   always be set correctly. Some web hosts implement php as a CGI in such
>   a way that they can turn it on or off for each virtual domain. 
>   Several $_SERVER and $_ENV variable values may be incorrect for
>   documents in subdirectory subdomains of these virtual domains. other
>   way to get Current FILE name

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
?>
```

Comment: I used $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] also,but not effect.any other suggestion?

Comment: what it gives? and please tell me your system config